# Как встроить telegram в android приложение?

Tags: java, android, json, telegram-bot, retrofit

Каким образом встроить чат-бота в Android приложение. Получать ответы от бота в виде json-массива и выводить? или пытаться интегрировать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно просто, но так как я ни разу не работал с ботом, то постараюсь помочь максимально используя свои знания. Насколько я знаю, суть бота, как вы вероятнее всего знаете, заключается в том чтобы человек общался с программой. Вы хотите обрабатывать ответы бота у себя в приложении, а для этого у вас должно быть несколько вещей:

1. Апи куда вы посылаете запрос - если это определенный бот, а вероятнее всего определенный, то вам нужно получать именно от нужного бота ответы. Для этого у вас должно быть апи. Чаще всего апи представлено в виде кусочка или целого адреса.
2. Класс-запрос (данные которые нужны для получения ответа от вашего бота) - это класс или кучка данных которые требуются серверу, для вашей идентификации. Вот к примеру, для вашей идентификации серверу нужен ваш логи и пароль. Дальше вам нужно отправить id бота или как там они идентифицируется. Значит у вас в вашей кучке данных будет три поля - логин, пароль и id-бота. И вы создаете класс который вмещает все эти поля, например:

`public class Regest{
             private Integer id;
private String login;
private Integer bot_id;`

```
public Regest(Integer id,String login,Integer bot_id) {
    this.id= id;
    this.login= login;
    this.bot_id= bot_id;
}

}
```

3. Класс-ответ - этот класс будет помогать вам обрабатывать ответ вашего сервера, то есть ответ вашего бота. В этот класс будет входить массив ваших сообщений и еще какие-то данные которые он будет слать, без примера ответа довольно сложно представить что там есть.
4. Послание запроса из активности и заполнение вашего вью-элемента:
   После того как вы все сделали вышеперечисленное, вам пора послать запрос. Для этого из активности вы должны послать запрос и полученные данные распарсить в вьюху:

```html
 public APIService apiService() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(APIService.class);
}

 public void getData() {
     mAPIService.auth(new Regest(login, password, bot_id)).enqueue(new Callback<SpeakWithBot>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SpeakWithBot> call, @NonNull Response<SpeakWithBot> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
здесь обрабатываете то что вам прислал сервер
}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

для обработки вашего ответа можете использовать как recyclerView с адаптером подстроенным под ваши данные, так и любой другой вью элемент. Если я где-то ошибся, то найдутся те кто меня исправит, или откорректирует мой ответ. Но я почему-то уверен что используя retrofit можно обрабатывать то что шлет вам в ответ ваш бот. Надеюсь что помог чем-то в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то, что нужно

Comment: если вам дам исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый :)